# How to get element triggering the easyautocomplete

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I'm using [easyautocomplete](http://easyautocomplete.com/) plugin for my project and I can't get the element which triggered that.

Here is the element:

```
<input class="form-control product-name" type="text" value="" name="item[0][product_name]" id="item_0_product_name" autocomplete="off">
```

Here is the jquery code:

```
$(".product-name").easyAutocomplete({
    url: function(phrase) {
        return base+getCurrentUrl()+"?phrase=" + phrase;
    },
    getValue: "product_name",
    list: {
        onChooseEvent: function() {
            console.log($(this).prop("name"));
            console.log($(this).attr("name"));
        }   
    },
});
```

The idea is, I would like to get the element which trigger that plugin and get one of its attribute, for example, the "name". But it always return "undefined" every time I choose an item from the list. I tried to log $(this), but only return "Object", not the input element.

How can I do this? Are there any other way to do this? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What is `base` set to? What is the result of `getCurrentUrl()`. What is the expected value of `getValue: "product_name"`? What type of data is being returned, JSON maybe, when you lookup the phrase?

Comment: Did you read http://easyautocomplete.com/guide#sec-data-remote

Comment: @Twisty no problem with the list, it worked fine. The problem is with $(this), which is my main question.

Comment: What do you see when you add just `console.log($(this));`? Can also try `console.log(this.getAttribute("name"));` I suspect that `$(this)` is being called by the anonymous function or the object that contains it. Wondering if you can pass an `event` object to your function and call the target of that. `onChooseEvent: function(e) { console.log($(e.target).attr("name")); }`

Comment: Thanks for the comment. console.log($(this)) will return "Object" just like I stated above. Maybe it is an empty object. this.getAttribute("name") returns error because getAttribute is not a function. I tried to console.log(this) and got this: http://take.ms/Ldgkc. I tried using e.target inside onChooseEvent, but it returns undefined.

Answer (score 2):

got it :) 
with the code below i'm able to get the name of triggered input (work fine in case of multiple instance)

check the use of 'elt'.

```js
$(".form-easyautocomplete").each(function(index,elt){
        $(elt).easyAutocomplete({
        list: {
            onChooseEvent: function () {
                console.log(elt.getAttribute('name'),$(elt).getSelectedItemData());
            }
        }
     })
})
```